# How to get an element at a specific index in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I am trying to make a tabbed browser code sample, but I am having trouble implmeneting the solution correctly. I have created a custom class `BrowserItem` which has two values, my custom web browser and a url string. I then created an ObservableCollection of type BrowserItem, in which I add new items to the ObservableCollection on a click event. For some reason though, when I call my `ShowTab` method in my MainPage to show the web browser instance that the user selects (from a ListBox populated by the ObservableCollection), I am getting an ArgumentOutOfRange exception. To illustrate, what I have so far is as follows:

BrowserItem.cs

```
public FullWebBrowser browser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string url
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Settings.cs

```
public static Setting<ObservableCollection<BrowserItem>> Browsers = new Setting<ObservableCollection<BrowserItem>>("Browsers", new ObservableCollection<BrowserItem>());
```

Where the Setting class above saves and gets the ObservableCollection from isolated storage.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void ShowTab(int index) 
    {
        this.currentIndex = index;
        //Settings.Browsers.Value.ElementAt(currentIndex);  //ArgumentOutOfRange exception
        int count = Settings.Browsers.Value.Count;

        if (count <= 0)
        {                
            FullWebBrowser browser = new FullWebBrowser();
            browser.InitialUri = "http://www.bing.com";

            BrowserItem Browser = new BrowserItem();
            Browser.browser = browser;
            Browser.url = browser.InitialUri;
            Settings.Browsers.Value.Add(Browser);
            BrowserHost.Children.Add(Browser.browser);
        }

        //SearchBar.Text = Settings.Browsers.Value.ElementAt(currentIndex).url ?? "";

        if (Settings.Browsers.Value.ElementAt(currentIndex) == null)  //ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        {
            FullWebBrowser browser = new FullWebBrowser();
            browser.InitialUri = "http://www.bing.com";

            BrowserItem Browser = new BrowserItem();
            Browser.browser = browser;
            Browser.url = browser.InitialUri;
            Settings.Browsers.Value.Add(Browser);
            BrowserHost.Children.Add(Browser.browser);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Settings.Browsers.Value.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Settings.Browsers.Value.ElementAt(i) != null)
            {
                Settings.Browsers.Value.ElementAt(i).browser.Visibility = i == this.currentIndex ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

The ArgumentOutOfRangeException first occurs on `Settings.Browsers.Value.ElementAt(currentIndex);` in the `ShowTab` method, and everywhere else containing the same statement. I would just like to show the webbrowser of the corresponding index value in the ObservableCollection in MainPage.

Comment: You must accept previously answered questions which can help other audience who are searching for similar issues.

Comment: have you checked the value of the index passed and the size of the collection?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that the collection was not being populated when initialized, so I adjusted my solution above. However, I still receive an ArguementOutOfRange exception when checking to see if a certain index is null in ShowTab on line `if (Settings.Browsers.Value.ElementAt(currentIndex) == null)`. The user is allowed to add an item on a click event in another page, and I pass in the newly created index value of the collection to my MainPage, and from there I must check to see if that index value contains a BrowserItem, and if not add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add items to the collection somehow from somewhere. There should be some code like

```
 Settings.Browsers.Value.Add(browserItemInstanceHere);
```

OR

```
 Settings.Browsers.Value = getSomeBrowserCollections();
```

You cannot get item from an empty collection and you index must not be greater than `Count-1`

Comment: Ok I just edited my solution regarding the `ShowTab` method, to first check to see if the collection is empty, and if so add a new item. That works. Afterwards, however, if the user wishes to add a new BrowserItem to the collection from another page, I want to check to see if the collection's respective index is null, and if so I must add another BrowserItem to it and then show this to the user. On line `if (Settings.Browsers.Value.ElementAt(currentIndex) == null)` how can I change this to check to see if the collection is null here (I still get the ArgumentOutOfRange exception)?

Comment: the code to add item and to show tab needs to be different. Show tab should only Show the requested tab. If the index is not in the collection just ignore and exit the function. `if(index > count || index < 0) return;`

Comment: Also, the list from which users select from should be fed from your collection so that the number of items is the same as size of your collection. this way the user will not select an index not in the collection.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I will try to change my solution when I can. I do still have a question about how to check to see if a certain index value in the ObservableCollection is null though?

Comment: You can't unless you put null there. E.g. `for(int i=0;i<5;i++) values.Add(null);` By that you initialized every location to null. But that doesn't make sense. If you didn't add anything object to that location, it doesn't exist. The `Add` method is incremental, starts at 0,1,2... as you call it. It can't jump a location.

Comment: OK thanks for your advice. I wasn't sure because I first used an array in which I checked to see if the index was null, then changed this to an ObservableCollection which is why I was still checking the index for a null value.

Comment: Yes array has fixed size so they have default values but collection tends to have the size of added items. So by default no items are added and the size = 0.